# Jquery - Add class on click of button / Remove class on click of body

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a div that I want to show when a button is clicked, and then if anywhere else on the page (including the original button) except for that hidden div is clicked then I want the div to hide again.

I think I'm pretty close, just can't get it right. This is what I have so far (as a basic example:

```
$(".clickme").click(function () {
    $(".toggletag").addClass('open');
});
if ( $('.toggletag').hasClass('open') ) {
    $("html").click(function () {
        $(".toggletag").removeClass('open');
    });
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/vgf6g/1/

I tried without the if statement at first but that of course caused the html click to override the button click causing the div to never show.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// flag : says "remove class when click reaches background"
var removeClass = true;

// when clicking the button : toggle the class, tell the background to leave it as is
$(".clickme").click(function () {
    $(".toggletag").toggleClass('open');
    removeClass = false;
});

// when clicking the div : never remove the class
$(".toggletag").click(function() {
    removeClass = false;
});

// when click event reaches "html" : remove class if needed, and reset flag
$("html").click(function () {
    if (removeClass) {
        $(".toggletag").removeClass('open');
    }
    removeClass = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vgf6g/3/

Comment: Thanks everyone! Went with your answer as it allowed me to have another div inside of the toggletag and still be able to click the inner div which prevents it from closing.

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/ch94M/2/

```
$(".clickme").click(function (e) {
    $('.toggletag').toggleClass('open');
    e.stopPropagation()
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (! $(e.target).hasClass('toggletag')) $(".toggletag").removeClass('open');
});
```

1. If you click the button first, it shows the div.  If you click it again, it hides.
2. If you click the hidden div, that is now viewable it does not hide.
3. If you click anywhere else it hides.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $el = $(e.target);
    if ($el.hasClass('toggletag')) {return false;}
    else if($el.hasClass('clickme')) {
        $(".toggletag").toggleClass('open');

    } else {
        $(".toggletag").removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju8mD/1/)

Comment: This works exactly as expected. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
$(".clickme").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".toggletag").toggleClass('open');
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest('.toggletag').length){
        $(".toggletag").removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2CnSc/)